# Service worker cache auto-versioning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Hoping you can help me with what I assume many of us have had to work through. It's simple enough, I have a `webpack.config.js` file where I'm referring to `package.json` for version.

The issue is that the service worker doesn't understand how to read the `process.env it needs, to pull out and keep the version updated.

Any ideas? I guess I'm missing some additional build steps in package.json, but not sure how to go about it and would love to learn how others deal with this issue of auto-cache-versioning in their service workers.

I added the definePlugin to the webpack config file, but can't read the value associated with it (in this case, the version number in package.json)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution I could work with (for anyone who stumbles across this in the future).
it involves incrementing the global cache version (`version++`). it shouldn't be done by one of the event handlers themselves.
I will investigate on staging how this actually plays out with asset updates and changes, but the idea is that we wouldn't need to do anything outside of the sw.js to implement audio-cache versioning.